# extjs+link remain in hover condition when i rightclick on it. How to void it

Tags: extjs

I am using links in my Extjs application, I am facing issue with hover state.

When I do rightclick on any link it shows the hover state till I click outside. Once I click outside it comes to normal.

I want to show normal state as soon as move mouse away from that link.

Here is my CSS.

```
.linkbold{
    color:#0080cc;
    font-family:Tahoma;
    font-size:11px;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-weight:bold !important;
}
a.linkbold:link, a.linkbold:visited{
    color:#0080cc;
    font-family:Tahoma;
    font-size:11px;
    text-decoration:none;
    background-color: #red;
    font-weight:bold !important;
    display:block;
}
a.linkbold:hover{
    color:#000000;
    font-family:Tahoma;
    font-size:11px;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-weight:bold !important;
}
a.linkbold:active{
    color:#000000;
    font-family:Tahoma;
    font-size:11px;
    text-decoration:underline !important;
    font-weight:bold !important;
    display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have change the **a.linkbold:active** color and remove underline on active state.
Color on active state changes to normal.